# Symfony2 Nested form: setter method priority/order

Tags: php, forms, symfony

3 forms, all nested one within the other.
Project -> hasForm -> Form
I need  project::setHasForm(), and then hasForm::setNameForm().

Currently it works in the reverse order, hasForm calls its setter first.
Is it possible to get this working so the top levels are set first (project::setHasForm first)?

--  Project

```
Class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('endDate')
            ->add('hasForm', HasForm::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'namespace..\Project' //example
        ));
    }

}
```

-- hasForm

```
Class HasForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('NameForm', NameForm::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'namespace..\HasForm' //example
        ));
    }
}
```

-- Form

```
Class NameForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('description')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'namespace..\Form' //example
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO it is not possible. Symfony form always set parent with filled childen.